# IE11 Debugging Capabilities

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie11-developer-tools

When debugging JavaScript I make heavy use of the console to evaluate individual lines of code, to retrieve instance values to test in 3rd party software (i.e. when building SOAP requests)

Now I've got IE11, it looks like the code I type into the debugger is executed (I can open alert boxes etc..) however the results are not printed in the console. Does this mean I now have to surround everything I type into the console with `console.log(JSON.stringify( /* ..expression.. */, null, 4 ))` statements?

Is there an easier way to return to the IE10 console behavior?

Comment: Your first problem is that you're debugging in IE. Your task execution will be increased greatly if you switch to a browser that constantly keeps up-to-date such as Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox (with Firebug plugin). I prefer Firefox myself, especially since they implemented HTTP/2.

Comment: I'm afraid I swear by the IE debugging tools (and always will), so much easier and more flexible then chrome/FF or at least they were in IE10.. if it works in IE it'll work everywhere else, if it's fast in IE, it'll be faster everywhere else, so it makes an amazing test/development platform just a poor browser. Also I'm paid by Microsoft so my browser is non-negotiable.

Comment: _`Also I'm paid by Microsoft so my browser is non-negotiable`_. I feel your pain...

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @MrAnonymous, please direct all (well deserved) praise to the comments above.

As noted above, this is an issue with the Debugger tools themselves and can be rectified by reloading the tools.